# what is the nail size i can use when it says 2-1/8 -inch Brad Nailer Kit?

Tags: nails, measurement

I have a nail gun that has this label `2-1/8 -inch Brad Nailer Kit`

does that mean i can use **2 inch** to **1/8 inch** nails?

i know that measures start from smaller to larger *e.g. 1 inch to 3 inch*

not sure why this is starting the other way around

or i misread it and sizes are not what i thought!

here is the link for the nail gun

https://www.homedepot.ca/product/ridgid-6-gallon-pancake-compressor-and-2-1-8-inch-brad-nailer-kit/1001382695

Comment: "2-1/8" means "two and one eighth".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means the **maximum** length it can use is 2-1/8" or 2.125" or 54mm

According to the Fine Manual located at

https://images.homedepot.ca/pdf/R213BNF_manual-pdf.pdf

The size range is 5/8" to 2-1/8" (.625-2.125", 15.9-54mm)

Comment: Remember to also look at the gauge , (thickness) if nails it can drive. A construction nail gun is a different beast from an 18ga pinner. Tools for tasks.